# Assign the value of onchange event to a global variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select option tags in my HTML which are populated via api calls

```
<select name="channel" id="selectName" onChange="getSelectedName(this)">
     <option value="">Select Name</option>
</select>
```

In my JS, I'm getting the values of each option with the following lines of codes

```
// get selected name
function getSelectedName(selectoption){
    let name = selectoption.value;
    console.log(name);
  }
```

This log the exact value of the channel in the console which is great.

**My Challenge:**
I have other functions in my project that need the exact values of the value being generated by that function.

How do I access that exact value globally so as to ingest them into other functions.

**What I have done:**
I've tried making the **name** global, however I have not had any headway with it.

Thanks in anticipation of your response.

Comment: Your other code could find the `<select>` element and the current selected `<option>`. The DOM is already global.

Comment: *"I've tried making the name global"* - That would work.  If the variable is in a scope where everything can access it then everything can access it.  It may not be the most ideal approach or how any given developer may do it, but it would "work".  *"I have not had any headway with it"* - Why not?  What did you try and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: @Pointy, what I need is the value of any selected option and subsequently use the value in other options

Comment: @David, logging the global variable in the console bring undefined

Comment: @OjoPhilipOdeniyi: Are you logging it *before* you've assigned a value to it?  Or *after*?  Instead of just guessing, please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate the specific problem you are observing during your debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are on the same page, you should be able to use

```
getElementById("selectName").value
```

This gets the actual selected value of your `<select>`

Comment: Do you mean without the function, it will work?

Comment: Yes, even without onChange it can work. onChange just detects when the value of the select changes, and acts accordingly. If you just need the value af such select at a given time you can access it directly

Comment: Wow! This is good to know, I will check it and give feedback. Thanks for prompt response

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `select` element value using getElementById. If you want to run other functions when select event happens use this kind of solution

```
function getSelectedName(selectoption){
    let name = selectoption.value;
    function1(name);
    function2(name);
}
```

Or you can use event handler

```
document.getElementById("selectName").addEventListener("change", function1);
document.getElementById("selectName").addEventListener("change", function2);
```

Comment: I've tried the first option before, but the issue is that the function runs when on change event is called and this is not what I want.